# ActiveMQ Consumers growing when using DefaultMessageListenerContainer in applicationContext.xml

Tags: activemq-classic

We defined an applicationContext.xml that contains containers for our ActiveMQ listeners. We are using DefaultMessageListenerContainer as shown below:

```
<bean id="jmsFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${smqurl}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="documentListener" class="org.abc.jms.SMsgListener">
    <property name="appProperties" ref="ApplicationProperties"/>
</bean>

<bean id="cachingConnectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsFactory" />
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="cacheConsumers" value="false"/>
</bean>

<bean id="container"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachingConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="documentListener"/>
    <property name="destinationName" value="SQueue" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10" />
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="20" />
</bean>
```

The problem is that the consumers keep increasing all the time and are not getting destroyed. Eventually, we encountered an OutOfMemory Exception.

We tried looking in the documentation and online but could not find any explicit way to destroy/release the consumers through the properties in the applicationContext.xml.

Has anyone else run into a similar issue? How did you eventually resolve the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We use [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html) for our JMS-integrations, it abstracts Spring's DMLC (DefaultMessageListenerContainer) and in our experience it works quite well.

Nevertheless, I would attack your problem like this:

1. The default cache level of DMLC is `CACHE_CONSUMER` ([documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html#setCacheLevel-int-)). Try tuning this property and see if it's the DMLC that's causing the leak.
2. Start with a heap analysis with a tool like VisialVM (it ships with the JDK, `$JAVA_HOME/bin/jvisual.vm`). It lets you see what's holding the objects in memory

If you're evaluating Camel, this [blog post](http://tmielke.blogspot.no/2012/03/camel-jms-with-transactions-lessons.html) from one of the developers at RedHat helped us fix some problems we had with transactions . If you're not using transactions, it shouldn't be a problem.